# Who is this pink-haired, bespectacled anime character?

Tags: story-identification, anime, character-identification

I was on Twitter when I met a girl with this anime icon and now I want to watch, but I don't know which anime is this character from.

[image: Close up on the face of a pink haired brown eyed anime girl looking sadly over to a blonde haired character]

Comment: I found it by using [WhatAnime.ga](https://whatanime.ga/?url=https%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3nIOD.jpg). The first results seem to be from some hentai anime, but the bottom two were a direct hit.

Comment: Close vote retracted: Based on the given answer, this does appear to be a sci-fi/fantasy anime.  However, I'll be leaving my downvote since this is a poorly-researched question in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

[Kobayashi](https://maid-dragon.fandom.com/wiki/Kobayashi) from *Kobayashi-san Chi no Maid Dragon*, or *Miss Kobayashi's Dragon Maid*, or  小林さんちのメイドラゴン. Synopsis of the show from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miss_Kobayashi%27s_Dragon_Maid):

> As office worker and programmer Kobayashi gets ready for work, she is greeted by a large dragon right outside her front door. The dragon immediately transforms into a human girl in a maid outfit, and introduces herself as Tohru. It turns out, that during a drunken excursion into the mountains the night before, Kobayashi had encountered the dragon, who claimed to have come from another world. Subsequently, Kobayashi had removed a holy sword from Tohru's back, earning her gratitude. With Tohru having no place to stay, Kobayashi offers to let the dragon stay at her home and become her personal maid, to which she agrees.
>
> Despite being efficient at housework, Tohru's unorthodox methods of housekeeping often end up scaring Kobayashi and bringing more trouble than help. Additionally, Tohru's presence attracts other dragons, gods, and mythical beings to her new home. One of these dragons, Kanna, shows up at Kobayashi's door, demanding that Kobayashi return Tohru to the other world. It is then revealed that she'd been exiled from the other world, and having nowhere else to stay, Kobayashi takes her in and becomes her guardian. As both Tohru and Kanna settle into the human world, Kobayashi starts to think of them as family.

[image: Poster for the show with "Miss Kobayashi's Dragon Maid" written at the top and then a black dragon looking at a triumphant looking girl stood in front of it with her hands on her hips: she has long flowing hair, wears a maid outfit and had horns out the top of her head and a long/large green dragon tail]

Comment: [This image](https://static.zerochan.net/Kobayashi-san.Chi.no.Maid.Dragon.full.2074815.jpg) shows the character with the red hair.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Yeah, her description says red-haired, but it's pretty pale. I'm not sure I would call it red or pink, myself. Perhaps coral?

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ [This chart](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-lvgBgsc0IpM/U6GZllp0WfI/AAAAAAAAFLc/9IWG-K9OO6k/s1600/how-men-and-women-see-colors.png) describes me pretty accurately. I guess coral, pink, or reddish would all work ;D